# How to finish this proof by contradiction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

**The Problem**: You were planning to study real hard this quarter so you took out *n* books on algorithms. However you had better planning than execution and you have not read a single book and they are now all overdue. The library charges one dollar a day for each overdue book. You have calculated for each book the number of days it will take you to read the book. You want to know what order to read (and return) the *n* books so that your overdue costs are minimized.

Sample instance of the problem : list T = {1, 4, 2, 6, 1, 4, 2}. Here there are 7 books you need to read and the first takes 1 day, second takes 4 days, etc.

Describe a greedy algorithm that will solve this problem and prove that your greedy algorithm is correct for this problem.

**My Work**
    Theorem : Selecting the books that takes the fewest number of days to read each time will minimize the overdue charge.
    Consider  an arbitrary instance of the problem and of size *n*
    Let *S* be the solution list in order of books to be read returned by our algorithm(greedy) 
    Let *O* be the optimal solution list in order of books to be read. 
    Let *i* be the first book(index) in which S and O disagree
    Know at *i<sup>th</sup>* step that S will choose book *F* that takes the the fewest number of days to read and that the number of books left at this point is *n - i*
    Because *S* and *O* disagree, *O* will choose another book *A* 
    We know that $F\le A$ so $(n-i)F \le (n - i)A$, meaning at this step, the option that *S* takes will contribute an amount less than or equal to the amount that option *O* contributes.

At this point how can I generalize and finish the proof by contradiction? I want to say that taking choosing book *F* will lead to the overall less charge and therefore statement "Let *i* be the first book(index) in which S and O disagree" would be false(no index), meaning that S and O are the same list and that my greedy algorithm is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Any order which has a longer book read before a shorter book will be more expensive than the order which swaps those two books round.

So any order which has a longer book read before a shorter book will not be optimal.

So any optimal order will have shorter books before longer books.  There may be more than one (there are eight in your example) but they all have the same cost.

Comment: How would you show that algebrically though? Can you continue off what I  have?

Comment: If  $t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n$ is an reading order of the times then the fine paid on book $i$ is $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^i t_j$ and the total fine is $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i t_j$.  Swap books $m$ and $m+1$ and the total fine increases by $t_{m+1} - t_{m}$ which is negative if $t_{m+1} \lt t_{m}$ so you do not have an optimal ordering if    $t_{m+1} \lt t_{m}$ for any $m$.  So any optimal ordering has $t_1\le t_2 \le \cdots\le t_n$ and if there are more than one then they have the same total fine since swapping books $k$ and $l$ makes no difference when $t_k=t_l$

Comment: Like not completely starting over. Off what I was doing with A, F, etc

Comment: Sorry I should be more clear. Like using this technique - http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs482/2007su/exchange.pdf